# Is my Javascript date before current date plus 1 hour?

Tags: javascript, datetime

If I have two Javascript date objects how can I see if my selectedDate is at least one hour into the future? Ex. if its 3PM, the selectedDate needs to be at least 4PM

```
var selectedDate = //somedatetime object
var currentDate = new Date(); // includes current time


if (selectedDate is before currentDateTime + 1 hour) {
    // return false
}
```

Comment: Check out moment.js. It will make life much easier

Comment: Use the answer I linked to then you can use [`getHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) to see how many hours are in between them.

Comment: Add an hour to the current date and compare the two? You might want to search for the two parts of the task on their own to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The value of dates are measured in milliseconds. So just look if it is 1 hour worth of milliseconds (3600000) behind or not.

```
if (+selectedDate < +currentDateTime + 3600000) {
    //more than an hour has passed
}
```